# Samsung Galaxy Note 3 : Tried to install TWRP, can't boot into recovery mode now

Tags: rooting, 5.0-lollipop, recovery-mode, twrp, odin

I followed the instructions for the Odin install method [here](https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxynote3internationalexynos.html) and and installed the [twrp-3.2.3-0-ha3g.img.tar](https://eu.dl.twrp.me/ha3g/twrp-3.2.3-0-ha3g.img.tar.html) using Odin (Reboot in Odin was unticked).

Everything went fine, but when I had to launch recovery mode by holding down <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> `+` <kbd>Home</kbd>, and the <kbd>Power</kbd> button (which is the combination to boot to recovery mode) it just booted to Download mode (which is accessed by holding down the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> key instead of the <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>)

The TWRP site says:

> Note many devices will replace your custom recovery automatically during first boot. To prevent this, use Google to find the proper key combo to enter recovery.

But I haven't been able to find anything that would indicate the key combination to have changed.

Of note is the fact that the normal Download Mode boot has the Warning screen where you have to press Volume Up to continue and says:

```
ODIN MODE
PRODUCT NAME: SM-N9005
CURRENT BINARY: Custom
SYSTEM STATUS: Custom
REACTIVATION LOCK: OFF
KNOX WARRANTY VOID: 0x1 (4)
QUALCOMM SECUREBOOT: ENABLE (CSB)
RP SWREV: S2, T2, R2, A3, P3
SECURE DOWNLOAD : ENABLE
UDC START
```

and then just the "Downloading... Do not turn off target !!"

Though when I use the Recovery Mode Boot it skips the Warning screen and it adds this line on top of all the previous lines:

```
Could not do normal boot.
```

It can still boot to the normal Android

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Note 3, Model Number: SM-N905, Android Version 5.0

Comment: can you boot to android?

Comment: @esQmo_ Yes booting to the normal Android still works

Comment: then,using adb, boot to recovery

Comment: https://link.medium.com/8jpdHDjezS read my article about easy way to boot into recovery if that helped you plz let me know

Comment: @TheColorman Did u manage to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem like you before. But I figured out the solution. We both downloaded and flashed the wrong TWRP version for Note 3 N9005: `ha3g.img.tar`. The correct one is `hlte.img.tar` which you can download on this link: https://dl.twrp.me/hlte/

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks! Using hlte instead of ha3g helped me!